# R - can't install swirl on mac

Tags: r, swirl

I have tried so many ways, still can't fix this. Please help me.

install.packages("swirl",dependencies = TRUE)

```
trying URL 'https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/CRAN/src/contrib/swirl_2.4.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 108666 bytes (106 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 106 KB

dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libbz2.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/joyjigsaw/anaconda3/lib/R/lib/libR.dylib
  Reason: image not found
/Users/joyjigsaw/anaconda3/lib/R/bin/INSTALL: line 34: 19472 Done                    echo 'tools:::.install_packages()'
     19473 Abort trap: 6           | R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES= LC_COLLATE=C "${R_HOME}/bin/R" $myArgs --slave --args ${args}
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package 'swirl' had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    '/private/var/folders/s1/tf4y03hx2x12jtcvv4wpd6sw0000gn/T/RtmpD4H8xM/downloaded_packages'
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
```

and I tried install from package archive file, it still didn't work out.

dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libbz2.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/joyjigsaw/anaconda3/lib/R/lib/libR.dylib
  Reason: image not found
/Users/joyjigsaw/anaconda3/lib/R/bin/INSTALL: line 34: 19505 Done                    echo 'tools:::.install_packages()'
     19506 Abort trap: 6           | R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES= LC_COLLATE=C "${R_HOME}/bin/R" $myArgs --slave --args ${args}
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package '/Users/joyjigsaw/Downloads/swirl_2.4.3.tgz' had non-zero exit status

this is conda info

```
           platform : osx-64
      conda version : 4.3.30
   conda is private : False
  conda-env version : 4.3.30
conda-build version : 3.0.19
     python version : 3.6.6.final.0
   requests version : 2.18.4
   root environment : /Users/joyjigsaw/anaconda3  (writable)
default environment : /Users/joyjigsaw/anaconda3
   envs directories : /Users/joyjigsaw/anaconda3/envs
                      /Users/joyjigsaw/.conda/envs
      package cache : /Users/joyjigsaw/anaconda3/pkgs
                      /Users/joyjigsaw/.conda/pkgs
       channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64
                      https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                      https://conda.anaconda.org/junzhi/osx-64
                      https://conda.anaconda.org/junzhi/noarch
                      https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/free/osx-64
                      https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/free/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/osx-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/osx-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/osx-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/osx-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
        config file : /Users/joyjigsaw/.condarc
         netrc file : None
       offline mode : False
         user-agent : conda/4.3.30 requests/2.18.4 CPython/3.6.6 Darwin/18.0.0 OSX/10.14    
            UID:GID : 501:20
```

this is my conda list

```
r                         3.5.1                    r351_0    r
r-abind                   1.4_5            r351hf348343_0    r
r-assertthat              0.2.0            r351hf348343_0    r
r-backports               1.1.2            r351h6402f54_0    r
r-base                    3.5.1                h539fb6c_1    r
r-base64enc               0.1_3            r351h6402f54_4    r
r-bcp                     4.0.2            r351h649bfe0_0    r
r-bh                      1.66.0_1         r351hf348343_0    r
r-bindr                   0.1.1            r351hf348343_0    r
r-bindrcpp                0.2.2            r351h32998d9_0    r
r-bit                     1.1_14           r351h6402f54_0    r
r-bit64                   0.9_7            r351h6402f54_0    r
r-bitops                  1.0_6            r351h6402f54_4    r
r-blob                    1.1.1            r351hf348343_0    r
r-boot                    1.3_20           r351hf348343_0    r
r-broom                   0.5.0            r351hf348343_0    r
r-callr                   2.0.4            r351hf348343_0    r
r-caret                   6.0_80           r351h6402f54_0    r
r-catools                 1.17.1.1         r351h32998d9_0    r
r-cellranger              1.1.0            r351hf348343_0    r
r-class                   7.3_14           r351h6402f54_4    r
r-cli                     1.0.0            r351hf348343_0    r
r-clipr                   0.4.1            r351hf348343_0    r
r-cluster                 2.0.7_1          r351h0b560c1_0    r
r-codetools               0.2_15           r351hf348343_0    r
r-colorspace              1.3_2            r351h6402f54_0    r
r-config                  0.3              r351hf348343_0    r
r-crayon                  1.3.4            r351hf348343_0    r
r-curl                    3.2              r351h6402f54_0    r
r-cvst                    0.2_2            r351hf348343_0    r
r-data.table              1.11.4           r351h6402f54_0    r
r-dbi                     1.0.0            r351hf348343_0    r
r-dbplyr                  1.2.2            r351hf348343_0    r
r-ddalpha                 1.3.4            r351h4496799_0    r
r-debugme                 1.1.0            r351hf348343_0    r
r-deoptimr                1.0_8            r351hf348343_0    r
r-dichromat               2.0_0            r351hf348343_4    r
r-digest                  0.6.15           r351h6402f54_0    r
r-dimred                  0.1.0            r351hf348343_0    r
r-dplyr                   0.7.6            r351h32998d9_0    r
r-drr                     0.0.3            r351hf348343_0    r
r-essentials              1.7.0            r342h8f48fb2_0    r
r-evaluate                0.11             r351hf348343_0    r
r-fansi                   0.2.3            r351h6402f54_0    r
r-forcats                 0.3.0            r351hf348343_0    r
r-foreach                 1.4.4            r351hf348343_0    r
r-foreign                 0.8_71           r351h6402f54_0    r
r-formatr                 1.5              r351hf348343_0    r
r-geometry                0.3_6            r351h6402f54_0    r
r-ggplot2                 3.0.0            r351hf348343_0    r
r-glmnet                  2.0_16           r351h0b560c1_0    r
r-glue                    1.3.0            r351h6402f54_0    r
r-gower                   0.1.2            r351h6402f54_0    r
r-gtable                  0.2.0            r351hf348343_0    r
r-haven                   1.1.2            r351h32998d9_0    r
r-hexbin                  1.27.2           r351h0b560c1_0    r
r-highr                   0.7              r351hf348343_0    r
r-hms                     0.4.2            r351hf348343_0    r
r-htmltools               0.3.6            r351h32998d9_0    r
r-htmlwidgets             1.2              r351hf348343_0    r
r-httpuv                  1.4.5            r351h32998d9_0    r
r-httr                    1.3.1            r351hf348343_0    r
r-ipred                   0.9_6            r351h6402f54_0    r
r-irdisplay               0.5.0            r351hf348343_0    r
r-irkernel                0.8.12                   r351_0    r
r-iterators               1.0.10           r351hf348343_0    r
r-jsonlite                1.5              r351h6402f54_0    r
r-kernlab                 0.9_26           r351h46e27c5_0    r
r-kernsmooth              2.23_15          r351h0b560c1_4    r
r-knitr                   1.20             r351hf348343_0    r
r-labeling                0.3              r351hf348343_4    r
r-later                   0.7.3            r351h32998d9_0    r
r-lattice                 0.20_35          r351h6402f54_0    r
r-lava                    1.6.2            r351hf348343_0    r
r-lazyeval                0.2.1            r351h6402f54_0    r
r-lubridate               1.7.4            r351h32998d9_0    r
r-magic                   1.5_8            r351hf348343_0    r
r-magrittr                1.5              r351hf348343_4    r
r-maps                    3.3.0            r351h6402f54_0    r
r-markdown                0.8              r351h6402f54_0    r
r-mass                    7.3_50           r351h6402f54_0    r
r-matrix                  1.2_14           r351h6402f54_0    r
r-mgcv                    1.8_24           r351h6402f54_0    r
r-mime                    0.5              r351h6402f54_0    r
r-miniui                  0.1.1.1          r351hf348343_0    r
r-mnormt                  1.5_5            r351h0b560c1_0    r
r-modelmetrics            1.1.0            r351h32998d9_0    r
r-modelr                  0.1.2            r351hf348343_0    r
r-mongolite               1.6              r351h6402f54_0    r
r-munsell                 0.5.0            r351hf348343_0    r
r-nlme                    3.1_137          r351h0b560c1_0    r
r-nnet                    7.3_12           r351h6402f54_0    r
r-numderiv                2016.8_1         r351hf348343_0    r
r-odbc                    1.1.5            r351h0a44026_0    r
r-openssl                 1.0.2            r351h6402f54_0    r
r-packrat                 0.4.9_3          r351hf348343_0    r
r-pbdzmq                  0.3_3            r351h32998d9_0    r
r-pillar                  1.3.0            r351hf348343_0    r
r-pkgconfig               2.0.1            r351hf348343_0    r
r-pki                     0.1_5.1          r351h6402f54_0    r
r-plogr                   0.2.0            r351hf348343_0    r
r-pls                     2.6_0            r351hf348343_0    r
r-plyr                    1.8.4            r351h32998d9_0    r
r-praise                  1.0.0            r351hf348343_4    r
r-prettyunits             1.0.2            r351hf348343_0    r
r-processx                3.1.0            r351h32998d9_0    r
r-prodlim                 2018.04.18       r351h32998d9_0    r
r-profvis                 0.3.5            r351h6402f54_0    r
r-promises                1.0.1            r351h32998d9_0    r
r-psych                   1.8.4            r351hf348343_0    r
r-purrr                   0.2.5            r351h6402f54_0    r
r-quantmod                0.4_13           r351hf348343_0    r
r-r6                      2.2.2            r351hf348343_0    r
r-randomforest            4.6_14           r351h0b560c1_0    r
r-rappdirs                0.3.1            r351h6402f54_0    r
r-rbokeh                  0.6.3                    r351_0    r
r-rcolorbrewer            1.1_2            r351hf348343_0    r
r-rcpp                    0.12.18          r351h32998d9_0    r
r-rcpparmadillo           0.8.600.0.0      r351h649bfe0_0    r
r-rcpproll                0.3.0            r351h32998d9_0    r
r-rcurl                   1.95_4.11        r351h6402f54_0    r
r-readr                   1.1.1            r351h32998d9_0    r
r-readxl                  1.1.0            r351h32998d9_0    r
r-recipes                 0.1.3            r351hf348343_0    r
r-recommended             3.5.1                    r351_0    r
r-rematch                 1.0.1            r351hf348343_0    r
r-repr                    0.15.0           r351hf348343_0    r
r-reprex                  0.2.0            r351hf348343_0    r
r-reshape2                1.4.3            r351h32998d9_0    r
r-rjava                   0.9_10           r351h6402f54_0    r
r-rjdbc                   0.2_7.1          r351hf348343_0    r
r-rjsonio                 1.3_0            r351h32998d9_4    r
r-rlang                   0.2.1            r351h6402f54_0    r
r-rmarkdown               1.10             r351hf348343_0    r
r-robustbase              0.93_2           r351h0b560c1_0    r
r-rpart                   4.1_13           r351h6402f54_0    r
r-rprojroot               1.3_2            r351hf348343_0    r
r-rsconnect               0.8.8            r351hf348343_0    r
r-rstudioapi              0.7              r351hf348343_0    r
r-rvest                   0.3.2            r351hf348343_0    r
r-scales                  0.5.0            r351h32998d9_0    r
r-selectr                 0.4_1            r351hf348343_0    r
r-sfsmisc                 1.1_2            r351hf348343_0    r
r-shiny                   1.1.0            r351hf348343_0    r
r-sourcetools             0.1.7            r351h32998d9_0    r
r-sparklyr                0.8.4            r351hf348343_0    r
r-spatial                 7.3_11           r351h6402f54_4    r
r-squarem                 2017.10_1        r351hf348343_0    r
r-stringi                 1.2.4            r351h32998d9_0    r
r-stringr                 1.3.1            r351hf348343_0    r
r-survival                2.42_6           r351h6402f54_0    r
r-testthat                2.0.0            r351h32998d9_0    r
r-tibble                  1.4.2            r351h6402f54_0    r
r-tidyr                   0.8.1            r351h32998d9_0    r
r-tidyselect              0.2.4            r351h32998d9_0    r
r-tidyverse               1.2.1            r351hf348343_0    r
r-timedate                3043.102         r351hf348343_0    r
r-tinytex                 0.6              r351hf348343_0    r
r-ttr                     0.23_3           r351h0b560c1_0    r
r-utf8                    1.1.4            r351h6402f54_0    r
r-uuid                    0.1_2            r351h6402f54_4    r
r-viridislite             0.3.0            r351hf348343_0    r
r-whisker                 0.3_2            r351hf348343_4    r
r-withr                   2.1.2            r351hf348343_0    r
r-xfun                    0.3              r351hf348343_0    r
r-xml2                    1.2.0            r351h32998d9_0    r
r-xtable                  1.8_2            r351hf348343_0    r
r-xts                     0.11_0           r351h6402f54_0    r
r-yaml                    2.2.0            r351h6402f54_0    r
r-zoo                     1.8_3            r351h6402f54_0    r
```

Comment: It might help to install the `bzip2` package with conda.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!   It worked!!!

Comment: This post seems a bit confused: `install.packages("swirl",dependencies = TRUE)` should not be attempting to install a tar.gx file, but rather a macbinary file (which are tgz). So the console outputs appear to be swapped.

Comment: @RalfStubner please post as answer.

Comment: @zx8754 done, thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you that `libbz2.dylib` could not be loaded. Since you are using conda, you should install the `bzip2` conda package.